# Typical Form Validation Approach

Tags: ajax, validation, post

I am looking to better understand the typical approach to form validation with AJAX.

I have found some information on this approach but it is hard sometimes to decipher what is the standard practice and what is a hack.

In my scenario, which is a common one, I have a dynamic form that the user submits and I want to ensure that the form input is valid.  If the form input does not pass validation, I want to re-display the form with the input submitted and display an error message.

From what I have read, it appears the best practice approach is to perform an AJAX POST on submit, essentially posting the entire form.  The server processes the AJAX post validating the posted items, and if all the items are valid, they are operated on (updates, inserts, etc to database).  Finally, the AJAX response returns the validation result.  If the validation result indicates success, a simple redirect occurs (the form is not re-posted since the form input was already processed and committed to the DB in the AJAX request).  If the validation result indicates an error, the error is displayed and the redirect does not occur.

Is this the correct approach?
Should the form input be processed during the AJAX POST, leaving just a redirect on the callback, or is it best to process the form input after the callback by re-posting the form?

It doesn't make sense to me to re-post the form.  In that case, I would think you'd have to validate the data twice for security reasons...both on the AJAX post and the re-post.

It is also possible I missed an even better, more standard approach.  Thanks.